# Use Dijkstra's algorithm to get shortest path when distance are as coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

I had a looked at other posts regarding this here at SO.

I'm trying to find the shortest path between nodes in a graph. Each edge between nodes has an `(X, Y)` coordinate.

I want to calculate the shortest distance from `Node I` to `Node J`. Once have that I want to add up all the X values and Y values from the coordinates in shortest path.

I have been stuck at this for hours and would love some insight.

Here is the code:

```
class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
    private int id;
    private List<Edge> adjacencyList;
    private Vertex previousVertex;
    private double minDistance;
    private Coordinate point;
    
    public Vertex(int id, Coordinate point) {
        this.id = id;
        this.point = point;
        this.adjacencyList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public Coordinate getPoint() {
        return this.point;
    }
    
    public List<Edge> getAdjacencyList() {
        return this.adjacencyList;
    }
    
    public void addNeighbour(Edge edge) {
        this.adjacencyList.add(edge);
    }
    
    public Vertex getPreviousVertex() {
        return this.previousVertex;
    }
    
    public void setPreviousVertex(Vertex previousVertex) {
        this.previousVertex = previousVertex;
    }
    
    public double getMinDistance() {
        return this.minDistance;
    }
    
    public void setMinDistance(double minDistance) {
        this.minDistance = minDistance;
    }
    
    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(this.minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }
}


class Edge {
    private double weight;
    private Vertex targetVertex;
    
    public Edge(double weight, Vertex targetVertex) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
    }
    
    public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }
    
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public Vertex getTargetVertex() {
        return this.targetVertex;
    }
        
    public void setTargetVertex(Vertex targetVertex) {
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
    }
}

class Algorithm {
    public void shortestPath(Vertex startVertex) {
        startVertex.setMinDistance(0);
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        queue.add(startVertex);
        
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex actualVertex = queue.poll();
            
            for (Edge edge : actualVertex.getAdjacencyList()) {
                Vertex v = edge.getTargetVertex();
                double weight = edge.getWeight();               
                double currentDistance = actualVertex.getMinDistance() + weight;
                
                if (currentDistance < v.getMinDistance()) {
                    queue.remove(v);
                    v.setMinDistance(currentDistance);
                    v.setPreviousVertex(actualVertex);
                    queue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex targetVertex){
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = targetVertex; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.getPreviousVertex()){
            path.add(vertex);
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;    
    }
}

class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    } 
    
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public static Coordinate readInput(Scanner in) {
       String[] temp = in.nextLine().split(" ");
       return new Coordinate(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]), Integer.parseInt(temp[1]));
    }
}
```

If I read from this textfile

> 3   //# of coordinates
>
> 0 0 // (x, y)
>
> 1 1  // (x, y)
>
> 2 0  // (x, y)
>
> 1 2  //edge between coordinate 1 to 2
>
> 2 3  //edge between coordinate 2 to 3

My test case would look like this:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] constants = s.nextLine().split(" ");
        
        final int N = Integer.parseInt(constants[0]);
        
        List<Coordinate> junctions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Coordinate> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            junctions.add(Coordinate.readInput(s));
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            paths.add(Coordinate.readInput(s));
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            int x = junctions.get(paths.get(i).getX() - 1).getX();
            int x1 = junctions.get(paths.get(i).getY() - 1).getX();
            int y = junctions.get(paths.get(i).getX() - 1).getY();
            int y1 = junctions.get(paths.get(i).getY() - 1).getY();
                
            Vertex vertex1 = new Vertex(paths.get(i).getX(), new Coordinate(x, y));
            Vertex vertex2 = new Vertex(paths.get(i).getY(), new Coordinate(x1, y1));
                
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y - y1, 2));
            
            vertex1.addNeighbour(new Edge(distance, vertex2));
            
            vertices.add(vertex1);
            vertices.add(vertex2);
        }
        
        Algorithm a = new Algorithm();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            a.shortestPath(vertices.get(i));
            
            for(Vertex vertex : a.getShortestPathTo(vertices.get(i+1))) {
                x += vertices.get(vertex.getID()).getPoint().getX();
                y += vertices.get(vertex.getID()).getPoint().getY();
            }
            
        }
        //This prints out "Total X: 5 Total Y: 3" (should be 3 and 1)
        System.out.println("Total X: " + x + " Total Y: " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how does this differ from normal dijsktra?

Comment: Would you like to implement your own solution? There's a library, called JGraphT, that could do the Dijkstra.

Comment: Do you mean that the weight of an edge should always be the Euclidean distance between its two vertices, rather than your current implementation's arbitrarily specified weight?

Comment: I actually just did this exact thing using lapjv (which implements dijkstra's algo as the back end).  I've been meaning to make a github repository for this for a while now, and you have given me motivation to do this when I get home tonight. I started copying all the files into an answer, but there are too many files and way too long. I will post an answer when I am done making the repo.

Comment: @Riko I never said it did. The only thing I'm trying to achieve in addition the finding the shortest path is, I also want to add together the X's and the Y's from all the coordinates in that very path.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes. The way I calculate the distance between two points right now is `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y - y1, 2));`

Comment: @Nilzone: I undestand what you mean. I have posted the answer.

Comment: By the way, this distance function is the textbook example of the A* algorithm. So if this isn't an exercise in Dijkstra, I'd advise having a look at A*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this part:

```
public void shortestPath(Vertex startVertex) {
    startVertex.setMinDistance(0);
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.add(startVertex);
    //The rest is omitted
}
```

Each time you run the `shortestPath` method, you should reset all the `minDistance` in all vertexes to infinity, not just the `startVertex`.

For all vertexes except the `startVertex`, the `minDistance` at the beginning should be set to infinity (or `Double.MAX_VALUE`) , or it will always be `0`.

Code:

```
for(Vertex v : vertices){
    v.setMinDistance(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    v.setPreviousVertex(null);  
}
a.shortestPath(vertices.get(i));
```

Further more, in your third loop of the class `Test`, you initialize same vertex more than one. So, what you should do is, pre-initializing all the vertexes and keep them in an array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    vertices.add(new Vertex(i + 1, junctions.get(i)); 
}

for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
    //Initialize x, y, x1, y1 here, I just skipped it
    Vertex vertex1 = vertices.get(paths.getX() - 1);
    Vertex vertex2 = vertices.get(paths.getY() - 1);

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y - y1, 2));

    vertex1.addNeighbour(new Edge(distance, vertex2));


}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but It didn't help much. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Would you be so kind and show with code?

Comment: @Nilzone- try above code, just added that in your last loop in `main` method class `Test`

Comment: @Nilzone- forgot one thing, you also need to reset the previousVertex

Comment: this code goes inside the last loop in `main` right?

Comment: @Nilzone- yup, just before you call `shortestPath` method, I think it is shortest way for now (not the best, but short)

Comment: still not working. But I think my logic in the third `for loop` in `main` is off somehow. When I output the number of how many other vertices a given vertex is connected to it always gives me 1 and 0's (with the test case in my question this is correct), but it also does this with a bigger test case where i know this is not correct. I loop though the `vertices` array and write this `System.out.println("Vertex: " + vertices.get(i).getID() + " has " + vertices.get(i).getAdjacencyList().size() + " Neighbours");`

Comment: @Nilzone- can I ask are those edges directed or indirected ? if they are not directed, so the way you are initialize those edges are wrong, just want to clarify this first :)

Comment: @Nilzone- I notice there are only N - 1 edges, so this actually is a tree? So you may not need to use Dijkstra after all

Comment: @Nilzone- oh, now I know, because, you may initialize your vertexes many time in the third loop, for example, if you have edge (1,2) and (1,3), you will initialize vertex with id 1 twice.

Comment: I'd really appreciated it if you once again could update your answer with code as I'm not completely sure as to how I would avoid it :)

Comment: @Nilzone- look at my updated answer, just change your third loop with my  version :) and added one more loop

Comment: right now the x, x1, y, y1 is removed. I'm supposed to keep those? :)

Comment: But here you are adding data to the `vertices` array twice?

Comment: @Nilzone- sorry, just edited, I will need to go now, so good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It doesn't work completely yet but I'll get there ;) Tonight I'm way too tired though. One question, what would I need to change if need if the edges is undirected?

Comment: @Nilzone- If the edges are undirected, so you need to add this line `vertex2.addNeighbour(new Edge(distance, vertex1));` into the loop.

Comment: but when you said something about N-1 lines and this being a tree. What algorithm would you recommend instead of this? :)

Comment: @Nilzone- because, in a tree, we only have one path from one node to each other, so actually, a BFS will be enough, you don't even need Dijkstra :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need to keep track for each node, what is the parent of that node in the Dijktra's tree. Once you keep track of that you are able to recover the shortest path recursively, traverse it and calculate what you need to know.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. Can you clarify please.

Comment: I you look at the last code I added in my question, I try to use the vertex, edge and algorithm classes to first find the shortest path, then add up all the X's and Y's in that path.

Answer (score 1):

As promised, I have created a github repo for my bipartite graph solver. You can take a look here: [Bipartite Solver on GitHub](https://github.com/dberm22/Bipartite-Solver)

As you explained, you have a set of points you are trying to find the minimum distance between. You have a whole bunch of X and Y coordinates, and you are attempting to find the smallest total euclidean distance between nodes.

The algorithm you are most interested in is Jonker-Volgenant, which implements Dijkstra's Algorithm for traversing nodes.

The library includes a bunch of [standalone executables](https://github.com/dberm22/Bipartite-Solver/tree/master/bin) you can run to test the code.

Let me know if this is useful to you.